# Sum values of detail rows (in extension) and put it in header (in extension)

Tags: customization, acumatica

Acumatica 2021 R1 - Customizations

I am using PXFormula to multiply a qty and cost to create a new extension field in the details of Physical Inventory Review (although I would think the specific screen wouldn’t matter.) That part is working fine. However, I then want to sum that new column’s values into a new extension field in the header. I can't get that part to work.

Here is the relevant detail code:

```
using PX.Data;
using System;

namespace PX.Objects.IN
{
  public class INPIDetailExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.IN.INPIDetail>
  {
        #region UsrExtBookCost
        [PXDecimal]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName="Ext. Book Cost")]

        [PXFormula(typeof(Mult<INPIDetail.bookQty, INPIDetail.unitCost>),
        typeof(SumCalc<INPIHeaderExt.usrTotalBookCost>))]
        public virtual Decimal? UsrExtBookCost { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrExtBookCost : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<usrExtBookCost> { }
        #endregion
  }
}
```

Here’s the header code:

```
using PX.Data;
using System;

namespace PX.Objects.IN
{
  public class INPIHeaderExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.IN.INPIHeader>
  {

    #region UsrTotalBookCost

    [PXDecimal]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Total Book Cost")]

    public virtual Decimal? UsrTotalBookCost { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrTotalBookCost : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<usrTotalBookCost> { }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

I feel it has something to do with the fact that these are extensions and that somehow the PXParent that is called in INPIDetail does not cover these extension.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Actually there is a clue in Acumatica's own code. In INPIDetail -- looking at the code for PhysicalQty, the use of PXFormula is commented out with t he comment that that calculation is being done manually... Looks like I need to do the same.

Comment: Its possible DAC attribute requires more work to refresh the amount properly. For edge cases using RowSelecting/RowSelected will not fail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53010150/7376238

Comment: Attribute PXDependsOnFields might help and other solutions to force the formula to re-execute.

Answer (score 1):

By any chance are you calling the PXFormulaAttribute.CalcAggregate in the row selected event of the INPIHeader. This should force the SumCalc to recalculate and update your value

```
PXFormulaAttribute.CalcAggregate<INPIDetailExt.usrExtBookCost>(DetailView.Cache, e.Row);
```